# How to change values of a Bootstrap Dropdown with a specific id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a typical Bootstrap Dropdown like this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Default option<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul id="my-select" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li data-value="10" role="presentation"><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
            <li data-value="20" role="presentation"><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This works perfectly for all Bootstrap Dropdowns without a specific id:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
    var selText = $(this).text();
    $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

My unsuccessful attempts on achieving this with an id are following:

```
var mySelect = $('#my-select');

mySelect.find(".li a").click(function () {
   ...
}
```

And

```
$("#my-select .li a").click(function () {
   ...
}
```

Comment: remove the dot  before the li => "li a"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("#my-select li a").click(function () {

}
```

`.`dot is used for classes

example:

```
<button class="myClass" ...>

$('.myClass')...
```

`#`sharp used for ids

```
<button id="myButton" ...>

$('#myButton')...
```

Comment: But don't I need dots for classes?

Comment: `li` is not your class, li is the `HTML Element`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#myselect").click(function(){
...
});
```

You don't need to specify li or anything as myselect is an id that uniquely identifies an element

Comment: This should work as the event bubbles up. But how do you know which link was clicked? You can't use "this" keyword because it represents myselect.

Comment: True that you cannot use this as this would represent my-select. You can however use event.target function that will give you the exact li that you are clicking on

`$("#my-select").click(function(event){
alert(event.target.innerHTML);
});`

innerHTML will show the exact content of your clicked li. Or you may get any other property of the li here, like id or nodename or class etc.